# Stock exchanges using open outcry

Tags: stock-exchanges

There is often discussion about efficiency of different trading systems. Is there some stock exchange using open outcry trading as of today?

Comment: Some of these, perhaps:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_exchanges_of_small_economies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris pointed out in his [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/stock-exchanges-using-open-outcry#comment27937_20690), smaller stock exchanges may use open outcry. There are several exchanges that use open outcry/floor trading in the US, however, although they aren't necessarily stock exchanges.

1. The NYSE still has a trading floor where some high-priced stocks are traded, according to [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_trading).
2. There are several futures/options exchanges in Chicago that still use these methods, like the [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange), the [Chicago Board of Trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Board_of_Trade), and the [Chicago Board Options Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Board_Options_Exchange).

Having visited the three Chicago exchanges I mentioned, I can personally vouch for their continued use of a trading floor, although its use is declining in all three.